# Add environment variable in app.yaml file during Google Build

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Build with `cloudbuild.yaml` to download an `app.yaml` file that includes environment variables for my `Python` based app. The `app.yaml` version used for the initial deployment does not contain the environment variables for security protection.

However, it seems this isn't working and the environment variables aren't being detected - as the `app.yaml` does not seem to be overwritten.

The following is my `cloudbuild.yaml` configuration:

```
steps:
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
args:
  [
    "cp",
    "gs://<path to bucket>/app.yaml",
    "app.yaml",
  ]
```

I understand the entrypoint for an app on `App Engine` is through `app.yaml` but I thought that if `cloudBuild.yaml` is included, this would be called first and then `app.yaml`.

If this isn't correct how else can I append environment variables to my app.yaml file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide me some precision? When you use cloud build for deploying appengine, the first step is to download an environment dependant app.yaml file because it contains secrets and you can't commit them? And even if the download is in success, it don't override your existing app.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `gcloud app deploy`, the deployment process won't take the `cloudbuild.yaml` file into account and will deploy your app along with your *unpopulated* `app.yaml` file.

To run a custom build step, you'll need to create a cloudbuild.yaml file as you did, define your custom build step and then add a build step to run the deploy command. That'd be something like this:

```
steps:
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
   args:
   [
    "cp",
    "gs://<path to bucket>/app.yaml",
    "app.yaml",
   ]
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
   args: ['app', 'deploy']
```

You'll then run the build by issuing the following command (in the same directory where you'd have run the `gcloud app deploy` one):

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

This will:

- Upload the current directory to the Cloud Build instance
- run the gsutil command from within that directory on the CB instance to retrieve the `app.yaml` file populated with your environment variables
- deploy your code to App Engine from the Cloud Build instance

Comment: Just to mention, as I tried this with a non-custom runtime, you cannot have app.yaml and cloudbuild.yaml in the same directory so if you are using a non-custom runtime you will need to move the app.yaml and other python files to a subdirectory and deploy with something like `args: ["app", "deploy", "subdir/app.yaml"]`